# Include a new file in the SSH configuration file

Tags: 18.04, server, ssh, filesystem, configuration

I have Ubuntu server 18.04.04 LTS with OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017.

I want to include a new created file `newFile` into `\etc\ssh\sshd_config`
I have add this line on the top of it `Include newFile` but when I restart SSH service it throws:

```
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: What is your end goal? AFAIK, `sshd` doesn't support splitting its configuration across multiple files (and hence doesn't have an `Include` statement)

Comment: Actually, mainly this is my prob [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645521/delete-lines-from-a-file-on-ubuntu-server-using-ssh-net) I didn't find any solution but, deleting the file before writing in it, but I don't want to risk an delete it, so I thought about including another file where I do want I want,

Answer (score 1):

> sshd doesn't support splitting its configuration across multiple files

Include statement has been added in 8.2

https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/c2bd7f74b0e0f3a3ee9d19ac549e6ba89013abaf

https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config

However it's not quite working correctly at the moment for Match directives, should be fixed in 8.4

https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3122